# Try to decode this ciphertext! It's probably enciphered multiple times

Tags: cipher

As the title says:

Your mission is to decode this ciphertext.
Hint: It's probably enciphered **multiple times**.

Yrj cxc myxn yfqqbs, myxn nxmb obfuuh xn dohqmxd..

Comment: While this is a nice cipher, and not any of the "usual suspects", it's still a substitution cipher with [at least 28 letters of ciphertext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicity_distance#Unicity_distance_of_substitution_cipher), so it is doomed to fall to a [computerised attack](https://www.quipqiup.com/). We usually add the [tag:no-computers] tag when such methods would ruin all the fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says the following

> How did this happen, this site really is cryptic

How to do it

> It's a substitution cipher which can be decoded using the following substitutions (replace top letter for bottom)
>
> ```
>  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>  FEDCBAZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHG
> ```

In other words to decode

> Use a reverse substitution cipher shifted by six places. This cipher is symmetric, so encoding is done in the same way.

Comment: Really brilliant work.